# Translation for a tattoo

Tags: translation

I'd like to make a tattoo with chinese symbols, and I want to double check if the words are correctly translated (I've used google translate). The words I want to translate are "lucky bastard", and the result received from google translate is "幸運混蛋". Is that the appropriate translation?

Comment: Is this question appropriate for the site?

Answer (score 2):

1. `幸運混蛋` is a very literal translation of 'lucky bastard'. The problem with this is that this is not an idiomatic expression in Chinese and can cause confusion. `混蛋` is also fairly derogatory, unlike the usage of 'bastard' here in English.
2. If you intend the meaning 'someone with astounding good luck', and are very mindful of idiomaticity, `幸運兒` is a possible, fairly general translation (see examples [here](https://www.omgchinese.com/dictionary/chinese/%E5%B9%B8%E8%BF%90%E5%84%BF)).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the cynic fever on tattooing Chinese characters on one's body, let me try to help:

> 幸运混蛋（Simplified Chinese）
> 幸運混蛋（Traditional Chinese）

They are correct translation for Lucky Bastard. But when someone reads it, it sounds a bit weird.

Maybe you could consider this term:

> 混世魔王

It means a demon/monster king who disturbs the world.